# are there any languages that have sounds in diphthongs that don’t occur in isolation?

Tags: phonetics, vowels, diphthongs

essentially i am doing an assignment for class in which we are building a pretend vowel system for a pretend language based on sound files we are given. i had two diphthong files with 5 other files that were isolated vowels. the sounds in the diphthongs were different from all of the vowel sounds i was given.

obviously it is a fake language with a fake phonetic system but it got me thinking if anyone knew any languages that had this phenomena ? A language that has sounds occurring in diphthongs that don’t occur outside the diphthongs as their own vocalic sound.

It’s possible that a language like this is impossible but I was just curious

Comment: You're looking for examples like having /aw/ but not /w/?

Comment: yeah something like that !

Comment: I think there are lots and lots of languages which have diphthongs that consist of sounds that may be identified with existing simplex phonemes, but whose actual production do not match any simplex phonemes. Examples from English have already been given; similar examples from other languages could easily be adduced: Faroese <ú> is [ʉu] when long, and there’s no phoneme /ʉ/; Irish has /uə/ as a diphthong, but only /ʊ/ as a short monophthong; Mandarin only has [ɛ] in diphthongs with /i/, though it’s usually analysed as being the existing phoneme /ə/, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Attic Greek lacked `/w/` and `/j/`, but had diphthongs `/aw/`, `/ew/`, `/aj/`, `/oj/`.

(It also lacked a short `/u/`, if you prefer to write `/au eu/`.)

Comment: In the case of /j/, it seems obvious that the diphthongs should be analyzed /ai/ /oi/ and not /aj/ /oj/ because 1) it would force you to posit an otherwise unused phoneme (even though this is apparently the case for /u/) and 2) since it *never* behaves as a consonant, the phoneme should be a vowel, not a consonant (which is true for /u/ vs. /w/ as well)

Comment: @ba As far as I know, though, the diphthongs always behave as single units rather than as two vowels next to each other. We also see a diachronic shift of /u/ → /y/, which didn't affect the second half of diphthongs; you could say that shows one phoneme /u/ splitting into two /u y/, one of which only appears after /a/ and /e/, but that doesn't seem any simpler than positing /w/ only in diphthongs to begin with.

Comment: @ba Re never behaves as a consonant—it never quite behaves as a vowel of its own either, though. That is, it's never the nucleus of its own syllable, because a diphthong acts as a single nucleus.

Comment: On the first comment: this doesn't seem to pose a problem, because 1) diachronic shifts in principle shouldn't decide how you analyze the synchronic phonology because they can create new phonological systems; 2) even if you do take it into account, the /u̯/ in a diphthong isn't pronounced the same way as the full vowel /u(:)/, so a different development is understandable; and 3) on the subject of diachronic shifts, is it easier to say that some /w/ were deleted and some were not, or /w/ was deleted and /u̯/ was not (and some /w/ were reanalyzed as /u̯/)?

Comment: On the second comment: the choice is either to admit two additional consonants that can only ever appear after certain vowels, or one additional vowel that can only appear in a diphthong. Maybe you have in mind a theory of diphthongs that I don't know of, but to me this analysis seems obvious

Comment: @ba Oh, don't get me wrong, my preferred analysis for Attic Greek would just treat the diphthongs as atomic units at the phonemic level. I think adding additional phonemes which can't stand on their own, only in diphthongs, seems unnecessarily complicated. That analysis just isn't useful for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

RP has [aɪ] and [aʊ] but no [a]. Phonemically you could analyse these as /æɪ/ or /ɑɪ/, or /æʊ/ or /ɑʊ/ respectively though

Comment: If you get a little more specific, the first parts of the /aɪ/ and /aʊ/ diphthongs are also not identical – the one in /aɪ/ is more retracted and closer to /ɑ/, and the one in /aʊ/ is more fronted and closer to /æ/.

Answer (score 4):

**Standard Mandarin**'s monophthongs in the usual five vowel analysis /i, u, y, ə, a/ (Pinyin *i, u, ü, e, a*) [and even if you include the apical vowel /ɨ
/ or /ɹ̩~ɻ̩/ or /z̩~ʐ̩/, Pinyin *i*] mean that /o/ and /e/ are only present in diphthongs /ou̯, jou̯, wo, je, ɥe, ei̯, wei̯/ (Pinyin: *ou, iou, uo, ie, üe [xue, jue, que, yue], ei, uei* [written as *wei* or *ui*]), bar some interjections, which are generally analysed as lying outside the normal system of phonology.

The existence of /ʊ/ as a monophthong is more debatable; it only occurs with the velar nasal /ŋ/    as a final. In Pinyin, it is written *ong* and thus analyses it as a pairing with /o/, making /o/ a monophthong; however, the five-vowel analysis follows Zhuyin (ㄨㄥ) and analyses it as /w/ + /ə/ + /ŋ/ (while still contrasting with ㄥ *-eng*). The notation /ʊ/ seems to be the preferred IPA allocation, giving yet another monophthong vowel.

Another example of a diphthong-only vowel is the case of /ɛ/, which only occurs in /jɛn/ and /ɥɛn/ (Pinyin *ian* and *üan* as in *xuan, juan, quan, yuan*). However, there is considerable variation in the realisation of this phoneme [æ ~ e].

**Cantonese** has fairly clear tense-lax distribution for certain monopthongs, which could be construed as producing 'new' vowel phonemes, e.g. /o/ only found in /ou/ and derived from mononphthong /ɔː/, /e/ only found in /ei/ from /ɛː/.

Answer (score 2):

RP's DRESS vowel is [ɛ]. Its FACE diphthong could be analysed as [ei] or [eɪ] (depending on whether the syllable is open or closed and whether the speaker is a HAPPY-tenser), in which case [e] occurs in diphthongs but not alone. Mind you, those diphthongs could instead be regarded as starting at [ɛ].